# Selecting Items in array - Javascript - Using Filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, indexof

Someone asked a question today about figuring out to select certain elements within an array from I to the end of the array and it made me wonder how to do that with the `filter` method.

One of the solutions that someone gave was to use `slice` and I understand that you're able to select from index to index, but how would you implement the `filter` method to do the same thing?

**Example**

```js
let arr = ['bug', 'cat', 'dog', 'flea', 'bat', 'hat', 'rat'];

let newArr = arr.filter(element => element >= element.indexOf(3));
    
console.log(newArr);
```

This is what I came up with, it doesn't work, but the idea is to select all strings that have an index of 3 or greater and return them into another array.

Comment: appreciate that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The runtime passes the index to the filter callback:

```
let newArr = arr.filter((element, index) => index >= 3);
```

Performance-wise you're still making a new array and copying values, so it's about the same as `.slice()`.

Comment: or `index > 2`.

Comment: ahh gotcha, that was pretty simple, i appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function with the filter criteria:

```
let arr = ['bug', 'cat', 'dog', 'flea', 'bat', 'hat', 'rat'];

function filterCriteria(item) {
  return item >= someValue;
}

function someFunction() {
  return arr.filter(filterCriteria);
}
```

"someFunction" will return the array filtered

Answer (score 1):

While you are visiting every item, you could use a counter and decrement it until the counter reaches zero. Then take this values.

```js
const
    fromIndex = i => _ => !i || !i--,
    array = ['bug', 'cat', 'dog', 'flea', 'bat', 'hat', 'rat'],
    result = array.filter(fromIndex(3));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: ah once again Nina, your solutions are too elegant for my brain. What is going on in your `fromIndex = i => _ => !i || !i--`? what is that underscore? lodash? or something else?

Comment: lodash is just a not used variable. the underscore denoted that (as convention). maybe the more classical empty parameter list is better understandable, like: `fromIndex = i => () => !i || !i--`

Comment: ah, but why do we need either `_` or `()`?

Comment: because of the closure and `filter` needs a function.

Answer (score 1):

the second argument in the filter callback is index. So You can do something like this

```
arr.filter((element,index) => index >= 3);
```